# Параметр vmpath в VMware

Tags: java, c#, vmware

Как узнать параметр vmpath в VMware для операции клонирования? 
https://code.vmware.com/samples/1067/vmclone?h=vmpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И снова привет :)

Нашел решение, в виде:

внесения **правок в исходный код** семплов и перекомпиляции.

Правки в виде **заменил параметр vmPath на vmName**